# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Controller #create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a rails application with 
1)User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  has_many :projects
end
```

2) Project Model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

3) CreateUser in db/migrate

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.references :projects

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

4) CreateProject in db/migrarte

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description
      t.references :users

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Now in my Controller, I have a function

```
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    if @project.save
      @user.projects << Project.find(@project.id)
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      redirect_to '/project/create'
    end
  end
```

But when i call http://localhost:3000/project/new, I receive following error :- 

-NoMethodError in ProjectController#create

-undefined method `projects' for # User

 
with

```
 @user.projects << Project.find(@project.id)
```

highlighted in the extracted source.

Am I entering the record into has_many relationship correct, or is my syntax wrong?

I ran the following code in the console the server,

```
user = User.find(1)
user.projects
```

I received this error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `projects' for #<User:0x00000001f5b508>
    from /home/harshil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activemodel-4.2.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
    from /home/harshil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activemodel-4.2.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
```

Thanks

Comment: this does not look like a valid code: ``t.refrences :users``. Did it actually run or is a typo?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out

Comment: So did that change help?

Comment: No, still the same error

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `CreateUser` migration is incorrect. It should not reference the projects. Projects should reference the User, which you have done correctly.

I believe this is confusing ActiveRecord

try removing `t.references :projects` from the `UserCreate` migration and try again

Comment: I tried removing the suggested code, then ran 
rake db:migrate
and also restarted the server, just to be sure, but nothing changed

Comment: did you rollback the migration prior to changing the migration? You'll need to get rid of the `project_id` column on the `users` table with was created by the `t.references :projects`

Comment: yes, I also tried doing '@projects.user' = '@user', but that is also giving me cant write unkown attribute 'user_id'

Comment: Post here your scheme.rb please.

Comment: ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150831160230) do

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "users_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

end

Comment: Look, `t.integer "users_id"`  is incorrect.
If your model's relations looks like
`project belongs_to: user`
`user has_many :projects`
you should remove `t.references :projects` from your create_users migration, and add `t.integer :user_id` to your create_projects migration.

Comment: If i change Project Model to belongs_to :creator, ::class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'creator_id', Then what should i change?

Comment: In this case you should rename your project's `user_id` column to `creator_id`.

Comment: but in the schema, it is still showing t.integer :user_id in the schema

Comment: It should be a new migration. Look, previous migration created field `user_id` in `projects` table. Now you can execute `rails g migration rename_user_id_to_creator_id_at_projects` which will contain `rename_column :projects, :user_id, :creator_id` and go on.